# javascript extract and convert into new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
[ {
            "contactId": "a87d096gd5fuop",
            "firstName": "John Doe",

            "registrationTypes": {
                "selectedOptions": [
                    {
                    }
                ],
                "subTotal": 1620.003
            },
            "foo1": {
                "selectedOptions": [
                ],
                "subTotal": 0
            },
         
            "events": {
                "selectedOptions": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "T1",
                        "value": "4550006:3",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "T2",
                        "value": "4550005:3",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "name": "T3",
                        "value": "4550003:3",
                    }
                ],
                "subTotal": 135.003
            },
            "freeNetworkingFunctions": {
            
            },

            "total": 1755.0059999999999
        },
        {
            "contactId": "a097f",
            "firstName": "David",

            "registrationTypes": {
                "selectedOptions": [
                   
                  {}
                ],
                "subTotal": 899.998
            },
            "foo1": {
                "selectedOptions": [
                 
                ],
                "subTotal": 0
            },
            "member": {
                "selectedOptions": [
                    {
                        
                    }
                ],
                "subTotal": 228.8
            },
            "events": {
                "selectedOptions": [
                    {
                        "id": "4",
                        "name": "T4",
                        "value": "4550002:2",
                     
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "5",
                        "name": "T5", 
                        "value": "4550001:2",
                       
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "6",
                        "name": "T6",
                        "value": "4550003:2",
                       
                    }
                ],
                "subTotal": 135.003
            },
           
            "total": 1263.801
        }
    ]
```

From the above array, I want to extract events, loop all the data and get only values. So my new array should be something like this:

```
[ {
    "contactId": "a87d096gd5fuop",
    "firstName": "John Doe",

    "registrationTypes": {
        "selectedOptions": [
            {
            }
        ],
        "subTotal": 1620.003
    },
    "foo1": {
        "selectedOptions": [
        ],
        "subTotal": 0
    },
 
    "events": [
        "4550006:3"
        "4550005:3",
        "4550003:3", 
    ],      

    },
    "freeNetworkingFunctions": {
    
    },

    "total": 1755.0059999999999
},
{
    "contactId": "a097f",
    "firstName": "David",

    "registrationTypes": {
        "selectedOptions": [
           
          {}
        ],
        "subTotal": 899.998
    },
    "foo1": {
        "selectedOptions": [
         
        ],
        "subTotal": 0
    },
    "member": {
        "selectedOptions": [
            {
                
            }
        ],
        "subTotal": 228.8
    },
    "events": [
        "4550004:2"
        "4550008:3",
        "4550003:3", 
    ],    
        "subTotal": 135.003
    },
   
    "total": 1263.801
}
]
```

So it should return the original array, however, events value data should be in one array.

```
 var arr = [];
 var r(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    data.push(arr[i].value);
 }
 var newData = [...data, arr]
```

However, this doesn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) twice - once on the dataset to iterate over the objects, and within that `map` to get an array of values from the `selectedOptions`.

```js
const data=[{contactId:"a87d096gd5fuop",firstName:"John Doe",registrationTypes:{selectedOptions:[{}],subTotal:1620.003},foo1:{selectedOptions:[],subTotal:0},events:{selectedOptions:[{id:"1",name:"T1",value:"4550006:3"},{id:"2",name:"T2",value:"4550005:3"},{id:"3",name:"T3",value:"4550003:3"}],subTotal:135.003},freeNetworkingFunctions:{},total:1755.0059999999999},{contactId:"a097f",firstName:"David",registrationTypes:{selectedOptions:[{}],subTotal:899.998},foo1:{selectedOptions:[],subTotal:0},member:{selectedOptions:[{}],subTotal:228.8},events:{selectedOptions:[{id:"4",name:"T4",value:"4550002:2"},{id:"5",name:"T5",value:"4550001:2"},{id:"6",name:"T6",value:"4550003:2"}],subTotal:135.003},total:1263.801}];

const out = data.map(obj => {
  
  // Destructure the selected options from the
  // rest of each object
  const { events: { selectedOptions }, ...rest } = obj;
  
  // `map` over the options to just get an array of values
  const events = selectedOptions.map(option => {
    return option.value;
  });
  
  // Return a new object with the new events property
  // combined with the other properties again
  return { ...rest, events };

});

console.log(out);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)